# SXA Search api doesn't work with Arabic facet value

Tags: sxa, solr, content-search, search-facet

I'm using Sitecore 9.3 and SXA 9.3, I use SXA OOB Search results components, when filtering with Arabic keyword in the facets, it doesn't bring data, although I checked the generated SOLR query, it works and returns data.
For example, **'sxatags=Tag'** works, but **'sxatags=تاج'** doesn't bring any items.

Comment: Can you verify whether it is the API call that doesn't return any data? That call should be something like "sxa/search/facets..."

Comment: @Gatogordo I apologize, I updated the question, I meant when filtering the search results with Arabic keyword

Comment: How are you filtering? I'm not quite sure I understand what you are doing. Are you using the filter components? Or scope? Add some more information, maybe a screenshot...